# OverlayEntry that captures PointerEvents, but also forwards them to the main app

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[Here](https://dartpad.dev/55219ab12e962e5bee7ba450c6a2a450), I am trying to create an OverlayEntry on top of the app that should:

- Capture, but also forward pointer events
- Render some information

The essence is:

```
  Overlay.of(context).insert(
    OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => Listener(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        onPointerMove: (event) => print(event),
        child: Text('Some more debug information'),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

However, the pointer events DON'T get forwarded to the app, but are "swallowed" by the Overlay.

Comment: you dont need additional overlay for that: you can use `GestureBinding.pointerRouter` to add some global route

Comment: Yes, but I also wanted to render some debug info at the same time (like pointer position...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out easier than expect. I just had to wrap the child of Listener into IgnorePointer:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    scheduleMicrotask(
      () => Overlay.of(context).insert(
        OverlayEntry(
          builder: (context) => Listener(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
            onPointerMove: (event) => print(event),
            child: IgnorePointer(
              child: Text('Some more debug information'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Still, the line with `behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent` is required. If I remove that line, I can't observe the events.